# How to show ** when typing password?

Tags: html, jsp

I create a Jsp page for log in - user name + password. However, when I am typing password it is showing on text box. Can anybody help me, how can I do this, when I type password it will show  **  .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `<input type="password">` instead of `<input type="text">`.

#### See also:

- [HTML tutorial - Forms](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/forms/)